# How-to for ViewPower UPS Management on Linux?

Tags: ups

Even when I use to prefer `Linux` over `Windows`, I must admit that the [ViewPower](http://www.power-software-download.com/viewpower.html) suite for **UPS management** is a *pain to configure* on `Linux`, and extremely easy on `Windows` (just install and go).

Isn't there any **tutorial** or instructions that could make ViewPower work on Linux?

Answer (score 2):

I've been hitting something similar. No Windows here to actually look at their product. Trying to install their last version (both i386 & x86_64) on some ubuntu wily, at best, their install script extracts some jre, I have messages about some missing /lib/libc.so.6.
Haven't tried on trusty or jessie either, last versions officially supported are ubuntu 12.04 & debian 6...

What I could recommend, is for you to try using nut/upsd instead.

Note that if your UPS is similar to mine (TP130), you will need to set your ups driver to blazer_usb (or blazer_ser).

Answer (score -1):

**Important:**

This application is designed for UPS Blazer. It is not guaranteed to work with other UPS brands

This application uses flash, and is disabled in firefox and chrome by default. You must enable the flash plugin.

Download flash in get.adobe.com/flashplayer

select `.tar.gz` for linux an download file

```
tar -zxvf flash_player_npapi_linux.x86_64.tar.gz

sudo cp libflashplayer.so /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/
```

Open Firefox
In "complements" section, select "plugins" and you'll see "Shockwave flash" and "activate always"

**ViewPower setup in Ubuntu 10x/12x/14x/16x x64**

Download app ViewPower

```
wget http://www.power-software-download.com/viewpower/installViewPower_Linux_x86_64.tar.gz
tar -zxvf installViewPower_Linux_x86_64.tar.gz
```

Next:

```
sudo ln -s /lib64/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 /lib/libc.so.6
or
sudo ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 /lib/libc.so.6
```

Next:

```
sudo chmod +x installViewPower_Linux_x86_64.bin
sudo ./installViewPower_Linux_x86_64.bin
```

Follow the on-screen instructions and wait for the program to start. The configuration and installation is the same in linux and windows. See HowTO [www.power-software-download.com/viewpower/ViewPower_user_manual.pdf](http://www.power-software-download.com/viewpower/ViewPower_user_manual.pdf)

[image]

Them press "open monitor" (Mozilla open in http://localhost:15178/ViewPower) enter with the default password "administrator" and configure it to your liking.

**Update:**

Please refer to the [following manual](https://powerwalker.com/software/ViewPower/ViewPower_V1.04-21012/ViewPowerHTML5_user_manual.pdf). There is another site that has the software available. However, keep in mind that this software has not had an update in years, therefore it may not work in recent versions of Linux. And adobe flash has been discontinued ([EOL](https://www.adobe.com/la/products/flashplayer/end-of-life.html))

Download [HERE](https://powerwalker.com/?lang=en&page=viewpower)